# Cant verify on facebook developers page

Tags: facebook, spring-social

I wanted to make my first spring social integration but I am stuck at verifying my account on Facebook developers page. It asks me for my phone number. I choose Serbia and my number is +381 64 xxx xx xx. But I don't know how to type it in that phone number text box. i tried do type 64 xxx xx xx and (0)64 xxx xx xx and I always get error: There was an error verifying your contact information. You have already confirm that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my profile, click activate text messaging, sent "F" to 32665 and got some code. After that, I removed my phone number from my profile. Then I go to do developers page and asks for verification, put my number and when prompted to type code, typed code which I receive when activating text messaging. I believe this is "hack" but it solved my problem.